# Selecting a drawn line with the mouse VB.net

Tags: vb.net, select, graphics, mouse, line

If I have a form with a line drawn on it how can I select that line by clicking on it with a mouse button, so that I can then do things with it like delete or modyfy?

Comment: Are you drawing the line in a Paint() event?...or using the LineShape from the PowerPacks?...or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some maths to see if the clicked mouse point lies on the line in question:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?419763-Check-a-Point-lies-in-a-Line-segment

However you may need to add some tolerance because the user may click one pixel away but still expect the line to be selected. Also you may need to think about what happens when two lines intersect or are drawn over one another?